# Drupal: how to let the customer to add specific nodes to a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to let my customers to add specific nodes to a view. I was wondering what's the best way to select which nodes belong to the view.

I was considering to use a custom tag, "inView".

I actually need a similar option to "Promoted to front page". Can I maybe have a front page which is not the home page of my website, but just an internal view page ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good experience with nodequeue. With it the client can choose which nodes and what order to show them. The interface is really good and easy to use.

Comment: awesome, I was wondering if I can also connect a new nodequeue to an existing view to use its draggable ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use taxonomy, CCK, tags, node types as filters to grab particular nodes for views. The quickest way is probably using Taxonomy, or a CCK field.